# How do you find results that occurred in the past week?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I have a `books` table with a `returned_date` column. I'd like to see the results for all of the books with a returned date that occurred in the past week.

Any thoughts? I tried doing some date math, but Postgres wasn't happy with my attempt.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You want to use `interval` and `current_date`:

```
select * from books where returned_date > current_date - interval '7 days'
```

This would return data from the past week **including** today.

[Here's more](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) on working with dates in Postgres.

Comment: This actually retrieves 8 days including the current day, not 7.

Comment: Good catch. Edited it to reflect that.

Answer (score 72):

Assuming `returned_date` is data type **`date`**, this is simplest and fastest:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE returned_date > CURRENT_DATE - 7;
```

[`now()::date` is the Postgres implementation of standard SQL `CURRENT_DATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html). Both do exactly the same in PostgreSQL.

`CURRENT_DATE - 7` works because one can subtract / add `integer` values (= days) from / to a [`date`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html). An unquoted number like `7` is treated as [numeric constant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-NUMERIC) and initially cast to `integer` by default (only digits, plus optional leading sign). No explicit cast needed.

With data type [`timestamp` or `timestamptz`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) you have to add / subtract an `interval`, like @Eric demonstrates. You *can* do the same with `date`, but the result is `timestamp` and you have to cast back to `date` or keep working with `timestamp`. Sticking to `date` is simplest and fastest for your purpose. Performance difference is tiny, but there is no reason not to take it. Less error prone, too.

The computation is independent from the actual data type of `returned_date`, the resulting type to the right of the operator will be coerced to match either way (or raise an error if no cast is registered).

For the "**past week**" ...

To **include today** make it `> current_date - 7` or `>= current_date - 6`. But that's typically a bad idea, as "today" is only a fraction of a day and can produce odd results.
`>= current_date - 7` returns rows for the last **8 days** (incl. today) instead of 7 and is wrong, strictly speaking.

To **exclude today** make it:

```
WHERE returned_date >= current_date - 7
AND   returned_date <  current_date
```

Or:

```
WHERE returned_date BETWEEN current_date - 7
                    AND     current_date - 1
```

To get the last full **calendar week** ending with Sunday, excluding today:

```
WHERE returned_date BETWEEN date_trunc('week', now())::date - 7
                    AND     date_trunc('week', now())::date - 1
```

`BETWEEN ... AND ...` is ok for data type `date` (being a discrete type), but typically the wrong tool for `timestamp` / `timestamptz`. See:

- [How to add a day/night indicator to a timestamp column?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/267877/3684)

The exact definition of "day" and "week" always depends on your current `timezone` setting.

Comment: Thanks this helped me very much.!

Answer (score 0):

What math did you try?

This should work

```
select * from books where current_date - integer '7'
```

Taken from [PostgreSQL Date/Time Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/functions-datetime.html)